# How to create WMS using mapproxy with Mapnik XML file as input?

Tags: mapnik, xml, mapproxy, config.yaml

I have Mapnik generated XML file for mapproxy input, but I didn't understand how to manage this into mapproxy.

I want to create WMS using mapproxy with Mapnik XML file input.

My XML file: myxml_mapnik.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Map srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
  <Style name="mapStyle">
    <Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer fill="rgb(0,100,0)"/>
    </Rule>
  </Style>
  <Layer name="mapLayer" srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">
    <StyleName>mapStyle</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="dbname">gis</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="host">localhost</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="password"/>
      <Parameter name="port"/>
      <Parameter name="table">polygons</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="user">apple</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
</Map>
```

Now I want to take this as a input in mapproxy

How can I do this?